# Entity Framework two tables same Design different names

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, entity-framework-4

I have School, User, SchoolUser, and MessageList tables. User can attend many schools and school can be attended by many users.

When I add School, User, and SchoolUser tables I see only get two enitities, because they have many to many relationship.

MessageList table is basically two columns only UserId, and SchoolId. when I update the model and add MessageList, Nothing gets added to the model and I get this message

> The model was generated with warnings or errors.
>   Please see the Error List for more details. These issues must be fixed before running your application.
>   Loading metadata from the database took 00:00:03.1234526.
>   Generating the model took 00:00:01.5980294.

However, I don't see any relevant errors or warnings.

Is the problem because UserSchool and MessageList have the same design?

Is there any work around the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to confirm that you have set primary keys on your tables? That is a common resolution for this problem.